# What are these annotations in IntelliJ for Java called?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-hinting

[image]

So I was just working on a Java project, and then these annotations popped up as I was typing. I found them to be really really helpful, but I have no idea what this feature is.

Could someone point me to the settings for this feature so I know when I can use it again in the future?

Comment: Syntax highlighting? What are you referring to? Annotations start with a `@`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

they are called **Parameters hint**. can disable them by going to

```
 File → Settings → Editor → General → Appearance → Show parameter name hints.
```

if you go there you can configure it to match your expectations.

link: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2016-3-user-interface

Comment: Thanks!! Helped a lot :)